# Rdlc:Error while loading code module

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, teamcity, rdlc

I couldn't build solution with `rdlc` report which contains custom assembly.

I got error :

> myrdlc error rsErrorLoadingCodeModule: Error while loading code
>   module: ‘mydll’. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'mydll' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

But then I found solution - added this custom dll to folder C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin .On local machine code builds without errors. But I use teamcity as build machine and teamcity also cannot build the code. The same exception.

How can I solve this problem? May be there is solution without placing dll in folder.